# Why is `global var` needed in a class variable for class method to access it?

Tags: python, global

```
class Test:
    num1 = 1

# CASE 1
# WHY GLOBAL HERE? But no global below in CASE 2
    global num2
    num2 = 2

    def printNum2(self):
        return num2

## FAILURE WITH NON-GLOBAL num2, why?
# should print 2, with instance
i = Test()
print i.printNum2()



# CASE 2
#
#AUTOMATICALLY GLOBAL SCOPE?
num1=1

def print1():
    return num1


print print1()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`class` creates a new scope. Since you use `global`, you force the name into the module scope instead of the class scope.

In other words, you have *not* created a class variable; you have simply created another global variable.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need global to make `printNum2` work correctly. Instead, use this:

```
class Test:
  num1 = 1
  num2 = 2

  def printNum2(self):
      return self.num2
```

You only need global if you want to do the following:

```
x = Test()
print num2
//instead of 
print x.num2
```

Comment: Perhaps that should be a class method (add `@classmethod` on the line before and rename `self` to `cls`), assuming it's really intended to be a class variable.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you affect a variable python automatically suppose that it is a local variable

Comment: Not only this is vague and propably not enough for OP to figure the detailed reasons out, it's also misleading or incorrect depending on your definition of "affect".

Comment: What I call affect is num2 = 2

Answer (score 0):

without "GLOBAL" num2 is a member of class so you should write self.num2

Answer (score 0):

You should use `self` (e.g. `self.num2`) to reference a class variable or an instance variable from a method. `global` does not create a clarr or instance variable.